# Can I power these components with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, power, led, sensor

I have 14 x TTP223 touch capacitors, 16 x 3mm transparent blue LEDs, and 2 x s90 servo motors.
I want to power these all. LEDs will probably never be on at the same time but better safe than sorry. UNfortunately I dont have a schematic but simply I want to read every touch sensor and while reading it if the touch sensor is triggered, by using sensors trigger pin, I want to light an LED.

Datasheet of the sensor: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1132200/ETC1/TTP223.html

I dont know how much current an LED needs. When meausured, a blue LED with around 2.8 volts on it draws about 7 miliamps which I found too low to be true. Also I am not sure that if the current will get drawn equally from each pin. Here is an example:

Say I have 10 LEDs. Say that If I use 1 I/O pin the system draws 40mA which is the limit. If I use 2pins connecting at the same node, would each pin supply 20mA or will there be problems. Thanks.

Comment: 7 mA sounds very reasonable. why do you mistrust your measurement?

Comment: also you have per-pin current limits. These are defined in the datasheet of your arduino's microcontroller (we don't know which arduino you have, so we don't know which microcontroller that is). Most microcontroller are *not* designed to source 20 mA on just any pin.

Comment: What makes you reluctant to read the data sheets?

Comment: I am reluctant because I am fine with theoretical part but since I have no practical experience I have no intuition on whether my measurements are right or not. Like it says 2 to 3 microAmps at the sensors datasheet which I found so small to be true. But again, this is because I have no intuition yet. Thats why I am reluctant about reading datasheets or trusting my measurements.

Answer (score 2):

> I dont know how much current an LED needs. When meausured, a blue LED with around 2.8 volts on it draws about 7 miliamps

The thing about LEDs is that you decide how much they draw. You can use a resistor or a constant current source but ultimately you should (and need to) decide how much current will go through them.

You can power LEDs directly from the Arduino's IO pins, but it very common to use transistors to drive the LEDs. Using a transistor an Arduino can turn on an LED or group of LEDs using a fraction of the current that will go through the LED. That way you're not limited by the 40mA or 20mA limits that the Arduino has.

Here's a blog post on how to use a transistor to turn on an LED:

https://arduinopak.wordpress.com/2016/09/21/how-to-turn-on-an-led-using-a-transistor-explained-by-arduinopak/

and here's a calculator to determine the resistor you need to limit current through an LED:

https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-led-series-resistor

Comment: I thought maybe I can use the arduinos 5V pin and to control that pin maybe I can use a relay. Examining the frist link, I believe I should use the 5V pin of BJT for collector voltage.  The "amplified" current will be drawn from the 5V pin of arduino again which still has a current limit. Am I right?

Comment: Don't use a relay for an LED -- relay coils take a relatively large amount of current to drive. You need a resistors on both the base and collector to limit current -- the base resistor limits current drawn from the GPIO pin, the collector resistor limits current through the LED.